# Git rebase successful but old commits exists

Tags: git, rebase

I ran `git rebase -i HEAD~7` and everything went OK. However, when typed `git log`. I see the rebase commit (squash several commits) as well as the old commits. So instead of having 1 commit, now I have 8 commits (1 - 7 old commits and 1 'squashed' commit).

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please tell us exactly what you did when the editor came up showing the last 8 commits.  My guess is that you took a wrong turn somewhere.

Comment: Before you continue, it may be a good idea to backup your repository, so that you can easily get back to the state you are in now. The state you had before the rebase is accessible from the ref `ORIG_HEAD` until you happen to run a command that overwrites it.

Comment: @jsageryd I use `git branch`. As long as I have a point to the old commits it’s easy to recover from a rebase.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Also valid of course, but perhaps not as easily explained to a novice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you typed `git rebase -i HEAD~7`, you would have seen something like this:

```
pick a873lnd 7 commits ago
pick 9gn283d 6 commits ago
pick k9mdn82 5 commits ago
pick k93m38f 4 commits ago
pick v382ndk 3 commits ago
pick 39mdji2 2 commits ago
pick alv93k3 most recent commit
```

The oldest commit will appear on top, and the newest commit will appear on the bottom.  When you squash commits together, you squash up, from newer to older.  So, if you wanted to squash the last recent 6 commits into the seventh, you would have made these changes:

```
p a873lnd 7 commits ago
s 9gn283d 6 commits ago
s k9mdn82 5 commits ago
s k93m38f 4 commits ago
s v382ndk 3 commits ago
s 39mdji2 2 commits ago
s alv93k3 most recent commit
```

Note that the most recent 6 commits got an `s` (short for `squash`) label, while the oldest commit is still `pick`.  Then, just save, close the editor, and complete the rebase.

If you *didn't* do this, then you did something other than squash the commits as you set out to do.  With regards to your current situation, if you are certain that you somehow only added a new commit on top of your history, then you could do another interactive rebase in which you just delete the line for that commit, then make the changes I suggested above.

Comment: Thanks @Tim Biegeleisen! This was exactly what I did! I will redo and do it slowly then. much appreciated!